# Is there any way to initiate "urgent animation" of an icon on the Unity launcher from command line?

Tags: unity, command-line, notification

It would be great if one could use it in the terminal for announcing that some time intensive job is done, e.g. "apt-get dist-upgrade; urg-anim".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the urgency hint using `wmctrl` (needs to be installed):

```
some_task ; wmctrl -i -r $WINDOWID -b add,demands_attention
```

Where `$WINDOWID` is a variable holding the terminal window's ID. Because that's rather long to type, you can set up an alias for it in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias set_urgent='wmctrl -i -r $WINDOWID -b add,demands_attention'
```

Then you'd simply run:

```
some_task ; set_urgent
```

Of course this will do nothing if the terminal is active at the time the `wmctrl` command is run.

Comment: If you want a stand-in for `some_task` (for testing), use `sleep 5`, which will pause for 5 seconds.  Also, you'll want to replace the quoted text "Terminal" with (part of) the title of your terminal, since the word "Terminal" may not occur in your terminal's window title (this can be configured via Edit->Profile Preferences->Title and Command tab->When terminal commands set their own title drop-down.).

Comment: Yeah, doing this via title matching is ugly. I have searched for a way to return the window id of the terminal and use it with the -i switch of wmctrl, but no luck.

Comment: The compiz wiki has some [really helpful info](http://wiki.compiz.org/WindowMatching#identify) on this

Comment: The problem with this is, that it's interactive - you need to click on a window to get the information. What would be great: `alias urgent_blink='wmctrl -i -r $(get me the window id) -b add,demands_attention'`. On the other hand, it shouldn't matter which terminal instance causes the launcher to wiggle.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, my final solution is: `alias yoo-hoo='wmctrl -i -r $WINDOWID -b add,demands_attention`

Comment: Oh, that's awesome! Didn't know about that variable. :)

Answer (score 1):

Install notify-send.

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade; notify-send 'Ubuntu updated' 'All updates complete'
```