# persistent notification for Unity launcher icons

Tags: unity, command-line, notification

I was delighted to learn about the `demands_attention` flag as explained here:
[Is there any way to initiate "urgent animation" of an icon on the Unity launcher from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40463/is-there-any-way-to-initiate-urgent-animation-of-an-icon-on-the-unity-launcher)

However, that notification is very brief - meaning I won't notice when I step away from the keyboard for a minute.

Is there a way to make that notification persistent so the icon is animated until the respective window is focused again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this isn't required; setting the `demands_attention` flag already adds a subtle indicator (blue triangle) to the very top left, which disappears when the respective window is focused again.

Comment: Ahhh, so THAT's what that thing is. Learned something new...