# How do I tell when a window demands attention?

Tags: unity, indicator, application-development

Unfortunately, it appears Unity's subtle [persistent urgency indicator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44639/persistent-notification-for-unity-launcher-icons) has disappeared in Oneiric - so I'm now considering [writing](http://conjurecode.com/create-indicator-applet-for-ubuntu-unity-with-python/) a replacement as panel/indicator applet.

However, I have no idea how to get notified when a window demands attention (or when such demands become obsolete due to the respective window being focused).

Some research suggests I'll have to hook into D-Bus, but I know neither where nor how.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I can adjust mine in CCSM with the Ubuntu Unity Plugin / Experimental / Urgent Animation.  Granted it's not a very long time attention getter but it does work on my laptops.  You can find a lot more personality for Unity here too.